# Regular expression to extract header name from c file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

How to extract headers from a c file that contains them like this?

```
#include <tema4header9.h>
#include    <tema4header3.h>
#include   <stdio.h>
#include        <longnametest/newheader.h>
#include <net/header.h>
#include  "last-test-Zhy3/DrRuheader.h"
#include <last-test-8fF7/a5xyheader.h>
```

I tried to use:

`sed -n -e 's/#include[ \t]*[<"]\([^ \/<"]*\/[^ \/]*\)\.h[">]/\1\.h/p'`

but it only works for those in subdirectories. also if i type:

`sed -n -e 's/#include[ \t]*[<"]\(([^ \/<"]*\/)+[^ \/]*\)\.h[">]/\1\.h/p'`

or

`sed -n -e 's/#include[ \t]*[<"]\(([^ \/<"]*\/)*[^ \/]*\)\.h[">]/\1\.h/p'`

the command does not work anymore. The output file should look like this:

```
tema4header9.h
tema4header3.
stdio.h
longnametest/newheader.h
net/header.h
last-test-Zhy3/DrRuheader.h
last-test-8fF7/a5xyheader.h
```

Comment: What is your expected output? `tema4header9.h`, etc.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` solution: This is using perl regex and printing anything between `"<"` or `'"'` on the lines which start with `#include`.

```
grep -oP '^#include.*(<|")\K.*(?=>|")' headers
tema4header9.h
tema4header3.h
stdio.h
longnametest/newheader.h
net/header.h
last-test-Zhy3/DrRuheader.h
last-test-8fF7/a5xyheader.h
```

If you are ok with `awk`:

```
awk '/#include/{gsub(/<|>|"/,"",$2);print $2}' headers
tema4header9.h
tema4header3.h
stdio.h
longnametest/newheader.h
net/header.h
last-test-Zhy3/DrRuheader.h
last-test-8fF7/a5xyheader.h
```

Comment: Just `'(?<="|\<).*(?="|\>)'` is suffiicient for `grep`

Comment: @Inian than it might extract some data from undesired line in the `file.c` like 

   `cout << "hey there" << "x>y" <<endl;`  so added `#include` as a safty measure. its upto OP to judge the risk.

Comment: I meant for the part to extraction within quotes and `<` alone,agree that previous part is necessary.

Comment: Can anybody tell me how to write the above grep like regex for C++ regex_search ?

Comment: Warning: these patterns do not capture all `#include`. Spacing and tabs are allowed around the `#` in C/C++. E.g. `# include <header.h>`. Correct: `grep -oE '^[ \t]*#[ \t]*include[ \t]*(<[^<]*>|"[^"]*")' headers`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sed -nr 's/#include\s+[<"]([^>"]+)[>"].*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk '{match($0,/[<"].*[>"]/);print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Like above:

```c
sed -n 's/\s*#\s*include\s*[<"]\(.\+.h\)[>"]/\1/p' input_file
```

but it is more precise, for example,
the `input_file` content is:

```c
 # include <stdio.h>
       #        include<stdlib.h>
    #    include    <time.h>
 #define LEN 8
 #define OPT 2
 #include <pthread.h>
 # include "mysql.h"
 #include "paths.h"
```

it can still print right:

```
stdio.h
stdlib.h
time.h
pthread.h
mysql.h
paths.h
```